# Can not create volume interface for an Output Mix object

Tags: android-ndk, opensl

I am having a problem with the volume interface in OpenSL on Android.  When I attempt to create an Output Mix object with the volume interface like this:

```
const SLInterfaceID interfaceIDs[1]={SL_IID_VOLUME};
const SLboolean interfaceRequirements[1]={SL_BOOLEAN_TRUE};

SLresult result=(*engineInterface)->CreateOutputMix(engineInterface,&outputObject,1,interfaceIDs,interfaceRequirements);
```

`result` comes back as `SL_RESULT_FEATURE_UNSUPPORTED` even though the volume interface is listed as mandated in the [spec](http://www.khronos.org/registry/sles/specs/OpenSL_ES_Specification_1.0.1.pdf).

If I change the `1` to `0` so that it ignores the requested interfaces, the output mix object is created, but obviously fails when attempt to `GetInterface(outputObject,SL_IID_VOLUME,&volumeInterface)`.

The only mention of the volume interface I see [here](http://mobilepearls.com/labs/native-android-api/opensles/index.html) is related to volume calculations when using `EnableStereoPosition`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android does not support the full OpenSL ES specification. If you look at the table in your second link, it shows that Android only supports Volume with Audio Player, but *not* Recorder, Engine or Output Mix. This feature is, indeed, unsupported.